# How to filter multiple data items in Cognos when those data items' values contain commas and/or apostrophes?

Tags: function, filter, filtering, analytics, cognos

I'm using Cognos reporting studio. So I have a data item I'm using in a report called [Employee Name]. [Employee Name] contains values such as the following:

Smith,John L
O'brien,Rick T
Johnson,Sarah H

I need to filter this list of names, however I am running into issues because of the presence of commas and apostrophes. Where I would normally filter the items like so:

```
[Employee Name] IN ( 'Smith,John L' , 'O'brien,Rick T' )
```

This doesn't seem to work because Cognos can not differentiate between which of the apostrophes and commas are syntax and which are part of the data item's values.

Is there a way to get around this issue? I'd have preferred to not have to remove the commas and apostrophes from the data item but I don't know if there's a way to get Cognos to recognize the difference within the filter or if there's another way to go about filtering this to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to escape them in your filter.   Try the following

```
[Employee Name] in ('O''brien ,Rick T', 'Smith,John L')
```